# How to ask for phone number of user during conversation only once in dialog flow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am trying to build a dialog flow and want to ask phone number of user only once during chat. For this I have tried asking phone number as a slot in intent. It works great if phone number is asking but the problem is that it is asking for phone number everytime. I just want it to ask once and save it. For this, I have tried webhooks but not sure if I implemented it correctly.

I have tried webhooking @sys.phone-number but not sure if I am doing it correctly.

```
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  function phonecheck(agent) {
    const phonec = agent.parameters.phone;

    if (!phonec) {
        agent.add(`Please enter phone number`);
    }

}

    let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('fees_intent', phonecheck);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

I want it to check it only once. If user has given phone number once, it shouldn't ask anywhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try and use the input-context for the phone intent. Whenever you want to capture a phone number, put the context say "capture-phone" as output-context to the intents and once the phone number is captured, you can set the lifespan of "capture-phone" context as "0".

If you are using slots, then also you can use the above context way. But if you have multiple slots in that intent, then use DB to save the phone. in the webhook, check if the phone is already captured by pinging DB. If not, ask for the phone number and save it in the DB.

Hope it helps you.